# How to set filter property in ImageView Android studio

Tags: java, android, css, android-studio, imageview

I have a yellow sparkline png and I would like to change the filter by adding some css. Colors will change according to positive or negative number.

So, if the number is negative, the line should be:

**CSS**

```
filter: hue-rotate(300deg) saturate(210%) brightness(0.7) contrast(170%);
```

If positive:

```
filter: hue-rotate(85deg) saturate(80%) brightness(0.85);
```

**ImageView:**

```
       <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:id="@+id/sparkline"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/coin_icon"
                android:src="@drawable/line_24"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                />
```

MainActivity.Java

```
ImageView sparkline;

sparkline = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sparkline);

if(datum.getQuote().getUSD().getPercentChange24h() < 0.000){
  ///red
}else{
    //green

 }
```

**EDIT:**

What I have:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

EDIT:

Now I used an ImageFilterView:

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.utils.widget.ImageFilterView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/sparkline"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                app:saturation="80"
                app:brightness="0.85"
                android:src="@drawable/btc_spike" />
```

But I still need to add the hue-rotate(300deg)
I couldn't find anything yet to change the color.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HSB (Hue-Saturation-Brightness) Model is also alternatively known as HSV where V stands for Value. More details about HSB colour Model with a graphical description and the Hue Wheel can be found on this [Medium](https://medium.com/innovaccer-tech/rgb-vs-hsb-vs-hsl-demystified-1992d7273d3a).

To apply an HSV Color filter on an ImageView you can use the method:

[public static int HSVToColor (float[] hsv)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#HSVToColor(float%5B%5D))

> Convert HSV components to an ARGB color. Alpha set to 0xFF.
>
> - `hsv[0]` is Hue ([0..360])
> - `hsv[1]` is Saturation ([0...1])
> - `hsv[2]` is Value ([0...1])
>
> If hsv values are out of range, they are pinned.

All you need is to create this float[] array with the above ranges and apply it into ImageView like below:

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
//hsv[0] is Hue [0 .. 360) hsv[1] is Saturation [0...1] hsv[2] is Value [0...1]
float[] hsv = new float[]{85f, 0.8f, 0.85f};
imageView.setColorFilter(Color.HSVToColor(hsv));
```

Result based on your 1st (yellow image) before and after applying the color Filter (green image) will be:

[image: orange_line]

[image: green_line]

If we pick a pixel sample from the attached Red/Green images the RGB colors are for `Red:R(209)G(63)B(84)` and for `Green:R(69)G(186)B(116)`. Now if we convert these RGB values to HSV values using an [RGB to HSV color conversion tool](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsv.html) we get the below:

**Red**

RGB: R(209)G(63)B(84) -> HSV: H(351deg)S(69.9%)V(82%)

In code:

```
float[] hsv = new float[]{351f, 0.699f, 0.82f};
imageView.setColorFilter(Color.HSVToColor(hsv));
```

Result:

[image: red_line]

**Green**

RGB: R(69)G(186)B(116) -> HSV: H(144deg)S(62.9%)V(72.9%)

In code:

```
float[] hsv = new float[]{144f, 0.629f, 0.729f};
imageView.setColorFilter(Color.HSVToColor(hsv));
```

Result:

[image: green_line]

Comment: Hi, How can I fill with color the bottom part? the part under the line?  Like full light color. I will update the question with an example

Comment: I've added the new image...Thanks for your help

Comment: I saw something here but still confuse. Please help me out. Thanks, 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode

Comment: Hi @Maduro it is better to open a new question for this issue. Do you have the graph x,y points or only the png image?

Comment: Heyy...yes, im using cryptocurrency data..so..I have price and date (string). but i have no idea on how to do graph in android lol. I will try to open a new question then and send you the link. But yes...Im getting data from coinmarketcap api: https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#section/Standards-and-Conventions and Im using the /v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest from the list

Comment: Hi @Maduro i found the new question you opened for this issue on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68881601/how-to-setcolorfilter-to-a-png-image
I have answered on how to draw a light color below the graph line using the png only file. In case you have also the x,y points you can use the  MPAndroidChart Library to draw any graph easily and colorise the areas you want.

Answer (score 1):

please try with below moethod hope it may help you

```
public static void changeImageColor(Context ctx,ImageView img, int color){
        try {
//            img.setColorFilter(color);
            img.setColorFilter(color,PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void changeImageColorNoMode(Context ctx,ImageView img, int color){
        try {
            img.setColorFilter(color);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, how do I represent/add the following CSS `filter: hue-rotate(85deg) saturate(80%) brightness(0.85);`

Comment: please try with also    
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="oval">
            <gradient android:angle="90"            
                android:endColor="@color/gray_dark_light"             
                android:startColor="@color/gray_dark_light"
                android:type="linear" />            
        </shape>

Comment: Can you please share screenshots only part of image from design where you want to implement this.

Comment: Please try also the imageviewfilter in place of imageview...., read it from https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/utils/widget/ImageFilterView        if still not work then try with ColorMatrix and canvas for bitmap and apply it on imageview.

Comment: Hey, I added the image. You can also check the coinmarketcap.com page.

Comment: I added the image: I added what I have..and what I need.